# "'BaseClass' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments." Partial C# / Protobuf class

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments, radix, datarow

I have a class `MyDataRow` which I derive from `DataRow`, here is my code:

```
public partial class MyDataRow : DataRow
{
    internal MyDataRow(DataRowBuilder builder)
        : base(builder)
    {
        // Initialization of variables
    }
}
```

The class is partial and has no members because it exists partially in a proto file (members are defined there, too).

Trying to build this produces ***error CS1729: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments***.
I'm a bit out of ideas, since I'm calling it explicitly with `: base(builder)`.

What am I missing? :)

edit: Upon request, here's the proto-part:

```
message SampleDataRow
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        ImAValue    = 1;
        MeToo       = 2;
    }

    // Some more enums...

    optional double    _member1    = 30 [default = 0];
    optional double    _member2    = 31 [default = 0];

    // More members...
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the partial part of the class and the implementation of the method?

Comment: I'd guess you have another constructor somewhere. Perhaps in another file (since this is a partial class).

Comment: That snippet alone builds for me. I reckon the other part of the partial class has a default constructor (or other constructor) that is not calling the base class's constructor (with a single argument).

Comment: @MatthewWatson You might be right. I looked in the proto-generated CS-file and there's a generated constructor `public MyDataRow() {}`. I think this implicitly calls the base class' default constructor.

Comment: @iknownothing That will *definitely* cause the problem. I guess you can just delete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocol Buffers creates a default constructor without arguments for the proto-part of my partial class, which leads to this error.
Thanks Matthew Watson for pointing that out.

Scrapping the C#-half of this class and instead working with the proto-definition alone would be a viable solution in my case.